# PHP Regex to find matching div tags

Tags: php, regex

Example: https://regex101.com/r/nHiyU3/1

CODE:

```
<div id="content">
    <div>
        <div class="col-image"></div> <!-- STOPS HERE -->
        THIS CONTENT HERE DOES NOT GET CAPTURED
    </div>
</div>
```

REGEX:

```
/<div id=[\'|"]content[\'|"][^>]*>(.*)<\/div>/sUi
```

So it stops where I've added the note to say

Any reason why? Have followed other topics on SO but can't get it to grab the whole lot.

So I know how to do it across multiple lines, it's finding the matching tag across multiple lines

Comment: If you came across this question in search for an answer, [please read this answer concering the use of regex for HTML parsing.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8913537)

Comment: Just go for `DOMDocument`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, it's easier to achieve this using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). For example:

```
<?php
    $html = '<div id="content"><div><div class="col-image"></div> <!--
             STOPS HERE -->THIS CONTENT HERE DOES NOT GET CAPTURED</div></div>';
    $domDocument = DOMDocument::loadHTML($html);
    $divList = $domDocument->getElementsByTagName('div');
    foreach ($divList as $div) {
        var_dump($div);
    }
```